# inserting multiple parameter values into a single column

Tags: mysql

I'm inserting into my database here with parameters from the form.

The form has 4 input fields (current_no, current_street, current_city, current_state). I've set it up so that the client can display each of these values on the web page, but what they want is to be able to view these values in a single column.

so basically from...

> current_no | current_street | current_city | current_state

to...

> | current_no current_street current_city current_state |

I decided I'd add another column to the table that'll store this "full" value and I figured that populating it would probably be easy but I think I'm missing something here:

```
insert into customers(current_address) values (current_no + ' ' + current_street + ' ' + current_city + ' ' + current_state)
```

Although this doesn't give me any errors, it only inserts the `current_no` value into the column.

How can I concatenate all the values (string types) into the column on database side?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `mySQL` use **[`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)**

```
insert into customers(current_address) values 
(
   (CONCAT(current_no,' ',current_street,' ',current_city,' ',current_state)
)
```

or [**CONCAT_WS()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

```
insert into customers(current_address) values 
(
   (CONCAT_WS(' ', current_no,current_street,current_city,current_state)
)
```

Comment: +1 for you because you showed OP two different methods: this is very professional! :)

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
INSERT INTO customers (current_address)
SELECT
  CONCAT_WS(' ', current_no, current_street, current_city, current_state)
```

Comment: Thanks, +1 for you, but answer goes to Mr Woo since he was first

Comment: @Ortund: I used a different function, but he was first, so the answer go to him, absolutely!! :)

Comment: `+1` for introducing `INSERT INTO..SELECT` :D

Answer (score 0):

Others have suggested `CONCAT_WS` and that's right.  The `+` operator the SQL language doesn't concatenate strings, as you have discovered.

But, please think about your plan of adding a new column to your table for this. New columns with redundant data aren't usually a great idea.

If you already have the columns with the data in them, I suggest you use a SELECT query when you *read* the table to create your concatenated column.  This will take advantage of the data you already have without placing redundant data in the table.

```
  SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', current_no,current_street,current_city,current_state) 
        AS current_address
```

Comment: Very nice observation. Yes I understand it would ordinarily work out better if I just referenced the existing columns, but there is a feature on the page that builds the gridview based on selection of columns. The user is therefore able to customize what data he/she sees in just a single click

Comment: Could you retrieve your data from a `view`, considering this gridview feature is driven by your columns?  Your application code won't be able to tell the difference between a table and a view (unless it uses `information_schema.columns` to fetch the metadata).